# A Wacky, Wacky Chessboard (That Makes No Sense)

Tags: cipher, chess, checkerboard

So yesterday I found *this* in the mail. A chessboard. But on the squares, things were written. Plaintext version:

```
LONGLIVE
HAPOTTER
DADDYJAM
ESLIKEST
HEMARAUD
ERSMAPAN
DWOULDLI
KETOSEND
```

On the back, well:

> KR6 KR1 KN7 QB8 QB4 QN5 KB4 QB1; 5C877471, -166128936; KR7 KN3 Q6 Q2 KR6 QB5 Q7 K5 K3

What did they say?

**UPDATE:**
I found another piece of paper in my mailbox today. It had this:

> KN1 QN1 K7 QR2 KR2 KR6 Q8 KB1 K1 K5 K3 QB1 QR2 Q2 Q3

**UPDATE:**
Yet ANOTHER piece of paper! Only this time it's plain text:

> Lav-Lav + _______ -> "Send him off! Red card!"

Comment: That's... strange. They look like they *should* be chess notations and directions but they're not. I wonder...

Comment: @North with the exception of the numbers in the middle, they are in fact old-school chess notation - King's Rook file, 6th row; King's Rook file, 1st row; King's kNight file, 7th row....

Comment: Each notation describes a square (not a piece movement), to elaborate.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: no, we need a hint.

Answer (score 12):

if you

> remember old notation referred to KB4 as f4 from the white point of view and f5 from the black point of view,

then

> alternating points of view gives the message:
>  meet me at 5C877471, -166128936 (then starting with black) i am unluky

which means

> he can't spell, but perhaps those are coordinates on Harry's map?

Comment: Could the numbers be GPS coordinates in hexadecimal? Apparently some devices use that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151896/convert-back-latitude-from-hex-data-greentel

Comment: There's no C on the chessboard - probably explains the poor spelling. The question is, why not come up with something where they are all present - leads me to suspect the answer is something to do with H. Potter ? ..

Comment: Hint: What is unlucky?

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

Well, the plaintext on the chessboard says,

> LONG LIVE HA[rry] POTTER DADDY JAMES LIKES THE MARAUDERS MAP AND WOULD LIKE TO SEND

I'm guessing the text on the back is supposed to be like a cipher using chess notations? They're not exactly any ciphers I recognize though... maybe like Kxr6?

Also this quote from *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* might help.

> "Mr Moony presents his compliments to Professor Snape and begs him to keep his abnormally large nose out of other people's business.
> Mr Prongs agrees with Mr Moony and would like to add that Professor Snape is an ugly git.
> Mr Padfoot would like to register his astonishment that an idiot like that ever became a Professor.
> Mr Wormtail bids Professor Snape good day, and advises him to wash his hair, the slime-ball."

Answer (score 4):

Using the text on the board as a map of sorts, and assuming that it's from white's point of view,

> KR6--> M; KR1--> D; KN7-->E; QB8--> N; QB4--> M; QN5--> S; KB4--> A; QB1--> T

Resulting in text

> "MDENMSAT" for the first part. I'm guessing the letters in the middle are a key of some sort.

Second list:

> "RADUMLOKA"

Neither of these are words, but there's a start.

[EDIT]

As @SteveV points out,

> You need to *alternate* between white and black's point of view, yielding "meet me at 5C877471, -166128936 (then starting with black) i am unluky"